# ffmpeg blend to exclude the top videos background

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to blend two videos, the top video named "top.mp4" was combined with some PNG files,but the combined video's background was black? why?

then i try to overlay the top.mp4 on another video (named bottom.mp4,was capture by android camera with QUALITY_480P)

but when I use Overlay filter i find the top.mp4 was not transparent and have a black background on the result.mp4.

I try to use blend filter  to combine top.mp4 and bottom.mp4 to exclude the top.mp4's black background , but i don't know how to use the blend filter.

here is my question:
1.is it possible to combine PNG files to a video and the video has transparent background? and then just use overlay filter,the result.mp4 will not have a black mask under the top.mp4?

2.if 1 is impossible, how to blend top.mp4 and bottom.mp4 to exclude the black background of top.mp4

my all output log

```
02-02 19:34:04.300 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: /data/data/com.demo/app_bin/ffmpeg -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/waterfall/waterfall_%04d.png -r 25 -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast -y /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim1.mov 
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:05:17 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
02-02 19:34:04.345 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
02-02 19:34:04.460 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/waterfall/waterfall_%04d.png':
02-02 19:34:04.460 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
02-02 19:34:04.460 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Output #0, mov, to '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim1.mov':
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0: Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Stream mapping:
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
02-02 19:34:04.470 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
02-02 19:34:05.565 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   46 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   12339kB time=00:00:01.84 bitrate=54936.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:06.070 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   59 fps= 56 q=-1.0 size=   22617kB time=00:00:02.36 bitrate=78509.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:06.580 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   71 fps= 45 q=-1.0 size=   32451kB time=00:00:02.84 bitrate=93605.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:07.095 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   88 fps= 42 q=-1.0 size=   42163kB time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=98124.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:07.610 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  109 fps= 42 q=-1.0 size=   52919kB time=00:00:04.36 bitrate=99428.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:08.095 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  128 fps= 41 q=-1.0 size=   64222kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate=102755.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:08.270 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  160 fps= 44 q=-1.0 size=   74397kB time=00:00:06.40 bitrate=95227.6kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:08.270 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  200 fps= 53 q=-1.0 Lsize=   77598kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=79460.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:08.270 7979-18576/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: video:77596kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002606%
02-02 19:34:08.270 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: 图片合成,exitValue=0
02-02 19:34:08.295 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: /data/data/com.demo/app_bin/ffmpeg -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/fish_isolate/fish_%04d.png -r 25 -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast -y /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim2.mov 
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:05:17 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.325 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/fish_isolate/fish_%04d.png':
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Output #0, mov, to '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim2.mov':
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0: Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Stream mapping:
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
02-02 19:34:08.410 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
02-02 19:34:08.750 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  200 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6606kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=6764.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:08.750 7979-18674/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: video:6604kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.023112%
02-02 19:34:08.750 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: 图片合成,exitValue=0
02-02 19:34:08.780 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: /data/data/com.demo/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/video1454412829452.mp4 -r 25 -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim1.mov -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim2.mov -i /storage/sdcard0/frame.ts -filter_complex transpose=1,crop=480:640:0:40,overlay=0:0:0,overlay=-2:-2:0,overlay=0:0:0 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/result.mp4 
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:05:17 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
02-02 19:34:08.810 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/video1454412829452.mp4':
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     major_brand     : isom
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     minor_version   : 0
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     creation_time   : 2016-02-02 11:33:58
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:07.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3099 kb/s
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 3074 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.82 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       rotate          : 180
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       creation_time   : 2016-02-02 11:33:58
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       encoder         :                                
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Side data:
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       displaymatrix: rotation of 180.00 degrees
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 124 kb/s (default)
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       creation_time   : 2016-02-02 11:33:58
02-02 19:34:08.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim1.mov':
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     major_brand     : qt  
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     minor_version   : 512
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     compatible_brands: qt  
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 79460 kb/s
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #1:0(eng): Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], 79458 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.920 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       handler_name    : DataHandler
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/anim2.mov':
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     major_brand     : qt  
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     minor_version   : 512
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     compatible_brands: qt  
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
02-02 19:34:08.950 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6764 kb/s
02-02 19:34:08.955 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #2:0(eng): Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgba, 480x640 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 3:4], 6762 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
02-02 19:34:08.955 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.955 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       handler_name    : DataHandler
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Input #3, mpegts, from '/storage/sdcard0/frame.ts':
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Duration: 00:00:05.13, start: 1.533333, bitrate: 1006 kb/s
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Program 1 
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       service_name    : Service01
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       service_provider: FFmpeg
02-02 19:34:08.985 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #3:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
02-02 19:34:09.000 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] using SAR=1/1
02-02 19:34:09.020 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] using cpu capabilities: none!
02-02 19:34:09.115 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
02-02 19:34:09.115 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
02-02 19:34:09.170 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/result.mp4':
02-02 19:34:09.170 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Metadata:
02-02 19:34:09.170 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     major_brand     : isom
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     minor_version   : 0
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
02-02 19:34:09.175 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:     Metadata:
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       creation_time   : 2016-02-02 11:33:58
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Stream mapping:
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> transpose (graph 0)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #2:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #3:0 (h264) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
02-02 19:34:09.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
02-02 19:34:10.250 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:10.745 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=    6 fps=5.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:11.295 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   11 fps=7.1 q=19.0 size=      11kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=  92.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:11.760 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   16 fps=7.7 q=19.0 size=      24kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 199.3kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:12.335 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   22 fps=8.5 q=20.0 size=      39kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 319.8kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:12.870 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   28 fps=9.0 q=19.0 size=      58kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 475.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:13.345 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   30 fps=8.3 q=20.0 size=      63kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 258.6kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:13.935 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   34 fps=8.2 q=20.0 size=      74kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 300.8kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:14.480 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   39 fps=8.2 q=20.0 size=      87kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 354.0kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:15.015 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   43 fps=8.2 q=20.0 size=      98kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 400.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:15.515 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   48 fps=8.3 q=21.0 size=     112kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 459.5kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:16.015 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   54 fps=8.5 q=24.0 size=     137kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 557.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:16.575 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   58 fps=8.5 q=24.0 size=     169kB time=00:00:02.19 bitrate= 628.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:17.090 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   60 fps=8.2 q=24.0 size=     189kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 515.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:17.605 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   65 fps=8.3 q=23.0 size=     228kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 621.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:18.090 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   70 fps=8.4 q=24.0 size=     269kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 731.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:18.655 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   76 fps=8.5 q=25.0 size=     320kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 870.6kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:19.115 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   82 fps=8.7 q=25.0 size=     374kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1019.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:19.620 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   87 fps=8.8 q=24.0 size=     419kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1142.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:20.120 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   89 fps=8.5 q=22.0 size=     434kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 885.6kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:20.685 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=   94 fps=8.6 q=22.0 size=     464kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 947.8kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:21.155 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  100 fps=8.7 q=22.0 size=     495kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=1010.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:21.685 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  105 fps=8.8 q=22.0 size=     523kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=1067.3kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:22.180 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  110 fps=8.8 q=22.0 size=     551kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=1125.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:22.685 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  115 fps=8.9 q=22.0 size=     576kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=1176.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:23.200 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  118 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=     592kB time=00:00:04.92 bitrate= 984.3kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:23.715 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  123 fps=8.8 q=22.0 size=     619kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=1011.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:24.265 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  127 fps=8.7 q=22.0 size=     638kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=1042.8kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:24.765 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  131 fps=8.7 q=23.0 size=     658kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=1074.5kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:25.310 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  137 fps=8.8 q=23.0 size=     700kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=1143.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:25.800 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  142 fps=8.8 q=23.0 size=     736kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=1202.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:26.345 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  147 fps=8.8 q=24.0 size=     771kB time=00:00:05.14 bitrate=1229.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:26.895 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  150 fps=8.7 q=24.0 size=     798kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1086.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:27.385 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  156 fps=8.8 q=24.0 size=     847kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1153.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:27.895 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  161 fps=8.9 q=23.0 size=     886kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1206.2kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:28.455 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  167 fps=8.9 q=23.0 size=     927kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1261.6kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:28.905 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  173 fps=9.0 q=23.0 size=     964kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1312.4kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:29.440 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  177 fps=9.0 q=23.0 size=     987kB time=00:00:06.20 bitrate=1302.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:29.995 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  180 fps=8.9 q=23.0 size=    1008kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1176.9kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:30.490 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  186 fps=9.0 q=21.0 size=    1048kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1223.3kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:31.015 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  191 fps=9.0 q=19.0 size=    1076kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1255.5kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:31.495 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  197 fps=9.0 q=18.0 size=    1103kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1287.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:32.040 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  202 fps=9.1 q=19.0 size=    1119kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1306.5kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:32.555 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  207 fps=9.1 q=20.0 size=    1138kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1328.1kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:33.140 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  213 fps=9.1 q=19.0 size=    1161kB time=00:00:07.01 bitrate=1354.7kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:33.695 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  217 fps=9.1 q=19.0 size=    1176kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1268.3kbits/s    
02-02 19:34:34.205 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  222 fps=9.1 q=19.0 size=    1195kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1288.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=4    
02-02 19:34:34.720 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  222 fps=8.9 q=19.0 size=    1195kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1288.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=13    
02-02 19:34:35.075 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  222 fps=8.7 q=19.0 size=    1195kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1288.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=24    
02-02 19:34:35.075 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: frame=  222 fps=8.6 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1233kB time=00:00:07.63 bitrate=1322.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=30    
02-02 19:34:35.075 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: video:1104kB audio:122kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.615799%
02-02 19:34:35.095 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size:  5784
02-02 19:34:35.095 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] frame P:221   Avg QP:21.62  size:  5084
02-02 19:34:35.095 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
02-02 19:34:35.095 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] mb P  I16..4: 17.6%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 21.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:60.5%
02-02 19:34:35.100 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 36.9% 18.1% 2.2% inter: 13.0% 7.3% 0.1%
02-02 19:34:35.100 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 30% 24% 19%
02-02 19:34:35.100 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 22% 17%  3%
02-02 19:34:35.100 7979-18716/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: [libx264 @ 0x2b447ef0] kb/s:1221.00
02-02 19:34:35.110 7979-18573/com.demo D/LLLLLLLLLL: 视频处理,exitValue=0
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? And post single-frame screenshots from t5op.mp4, bottom.mp4 and PNG sequence.

Comment: here is the frame     https://goo.gl/photos/w9KZgTRQk9WaPkt16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate transparent video from PNGs by using `-c:v png -pix_fmt rgba` and output to `top.mov`

**Edit**: this command skips the intermediate MOVs from PNGs

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/temp/video1454412829452.mp4 -framerate 25 -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/waterfall/waterfall_%04d.png -framerate 25 -i /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/magic/waterfall/fish_isolate/fish_%04d.png -i /storage/sdcard0/frame.ts -filter_complex transpose=1,crop=480:640:0:40,overlay=0:0:0,overlay=-2:-2:0,overlay=0:0:0 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -y /storage/sdcard0/baishiMagic/result.mp4
```

Comment: Paste your current commands and console output and I'll modify them.

Comment: could you please give me the total command,
my command: "ffmpeg -y -i waterfall_%04d.png -c:v png -pix_fmt rgba top.mov ",but failed with "At least one output file must be specified"

Comment: Rerun your command with `-report` added to the end and paste the text file generated

Comment: sorry I can't get the report file, could please just give me a total command example? just like "ffmpeg -r 0.5 -i image%04d.png  -vcodec mpeg4 top.mov"?

Comment: The command you tried should work, so I need to see the console output to see what went wrong.

Comment: but there is another question... the top.mov is so large....i use 200 png files generate the top.mov, the mov file size is almost 100M..

Comment: `-vcodec png` and `-c:v png` are the same thing, unless you're using an old version of ffmpeg. Try `-vcodec qtrle` for a possibly smaller file.

Comment: I used qtrle but the size  is still very big,almost 100M (200 png files, each file is about 100K,generate 8 second video),is there any idea to reolve the problem? 
if i use vcodec mpeg4 the top.mov is just 1-2M..... but it lost alpha,the backround color is black ,then if  overlay the top.mov on other video, it's not transparent(with a black background)

Comment: Please paste the overlay command and its console output into the question.

Comment: here i used -vodec copy but when i use png or  qtrle,  it's the same result ,very big

Comment: check my all log please

Comment: Use edited command. Since your ffmpeg version is old (Oct 2014), I don't know if `-framerate` is recognized. Either upgrade or use `-r 25` instead. I haven't debugged the rest of your command.